# Formatted text in TextSwitcher?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using a `TextSwitcher`, however the `setText()` method takes in a `CharSequence` rather than an resID integer. If I use `getString(resID)` the formatting is stripped out. Is there a way to get formatted text (with bold and italics) to show in a `TextSwitcher`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn about `SpannableStringBuilder`, this is so useful in producing styled text.

Then just create your formatted strings like:

```
SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
sb.append("Hi, abc!");
sb.setSpan(new ForegroundSpan(0xffff0000), 4, 7, 0); // set characters 4 to 7 to red
yourTextWidget.setText(sb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**Edit:** `TextSwitcher` is just a small wrapper to `ViewSwitcher`. Examining the sources of `TextSwitcher` reveals:

```
/**
 * Sets the text of the next view and switches to the next view. This can
 * be used to animate the old text out and animate the next text in.
 *
 * @param text the new text to display
 */
public void setText(CharSequence text) {
    final TextView t = (TextView) getNextView();
    t.setText(text);
    showNext();
}
```

So, just call this instead of `setText`:

```
final TextView t = (TextView) yourWidget.getNextView();
t.setText(sb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
yourWidget.showNext();
```

Comment: This comment field doesn't support rich formatting, so I just edit the answer above :)

Comment: Thanks! That worked with a small change, I needed to replace "t.setText(sb, BufferType.SPANNABLE);" with "t.setText(R.string.blah);"

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a formatted text to a `TextView`, you need to use [Html.fromHtml(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29). Keep in mind, `Spanned`implements from `CharSequence`.

You can also use [Resources.getText(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getText%28int%29) to get a styled `CharSequence` from your application resources.

Comment: I tried this, however TextSwitcher still seems to ignore the <b> tags in my string.